# Update and Upgrade updated mysql and now "Job failed to start"

Tags: mysql

I ran `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` earlier today and I had a conflict with the `my.cnf` file I saw default=n so I pressed "n" and went on my merry way.

I now can't start mysql via `service mysql start`, I'm getting:

```
start: Job failed to start
```

I'm assuming I updated mysql and it's using an old `cnf` file. Is this possible?

Comment: Try `/etc/init.d/mysql start`. Does it start?

Comment: says to use `service mysql start` and spouts `start: Job failed to start`